# Sharepoint canCurrentUserEditMembership API call returns 'false', for user with 'Full Control' permission

Tags: sharepoint

In the sharepoint site, The user is in the 'Admins' group, which has the 'Full Control' permission for the sharepoint site. And this user is also the 'Owner' in 'Team members' group, where only the group owner can edit membership.

But When sending '_api/web/sitegroups(groupid)/canCurrentUserEditMembership' call, it returns with a 'false'. For 'canCurrentUserViewMembership' it returns 'true'.

And also obviously, the user is only able to send GET request to the group using REST API. Any POST request fails with a 403 access denied status.

Since some materials I referred to suggested, I checked if the master page is checked out or in a pending  approval status. And It is NOT.

I am using a sharepoint Add-In application, and in it's AppMainfest.xml I have also added this,

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list" Right="FullControl" />
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
  </AppPermissionRequests>
```

But Manually by logging in to the sharepoint site user is able to view, add, remove users in user group.

I'm struggling to solve this. Any help to solve this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the other permission levels in AppMainfest.xml and giving FullControl permission in sitecollection level.

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
  </AppPermissionRequests>
```